# Execute shell script when the file is opened

Tags: shell, terminal, scp

I want to make a shell script, which is executed when it is clicked on. I know you can do this with the Terminal command `chmod u+x (filename)` but I want to be able to send the file let's say by email or `scp`, and it should still be executed when clicked on by the new user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think that is possible. The executability of the file is not **an attribute within the file which tells the system to execute it. Its something you tell the system to do**. I guess it is a security measure, regarding running maybe a risky command, lets say, rm -rf an important system folder.